# Initialize full dependency tree in Maven aggregator plugin

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have an aggregator plugin in Maven with an injected `DependencyGraphBuilder`. My goal is to resolve the `DependencyNode` of the current project with all child nodes initialized as well.

```
@Mojo(name = "mojo", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.SITE,
  requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE, aggregator = true)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Component(hint = "default")
    private DependencyGraphBuilder dependencyGraphBuilder;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${reactorProjects}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private List<MavenProject> reactorProjects;       

}
```

Currently, if i try to resolve to root node, i am only able to get the dependencies of the current project. I assume that Maven did not resolve that dependencies (only for the current project).

```
dependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(project, null, reactorProjects);
```

**Summing up:**

How can i resolve the child nodes to build to full dependency tree
using `DependencyGraphBuilder` in a Maven reactor project or is this not possible for aggregator projects?

**Additional Info:**

I have looked at similar questions, but all of those did not assume an aggregator project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to implement `mvn dependency:tree` why not to copy the solution from the Maven Dependency Plugin. Take a look at [TreeMojo](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/tree/TreeMojo.java#L246) which also uses `DependencyGraphBuilder` with [DependencyNodeVisitor](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/tree/TreeMojo.java#L345).

Comment: Yeah, i have looked into that, but i suppose it is meant to be used for each module. I would face the exact same problem as above is ecexuted in an aggregator.